# Java recursion in array- find path from array[0] to array[length-1]

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, path

I'm trying to write recursive method that return true if there is a path from a[0] to a[a.length-1] when you can sum or substract the a[i].
for example in the array a={2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5} the method returns true since 0+2-1+4+2-3+4 = 8 = a[a.length-1].
I tried few methods but I'm getting stack overflow or wrong output.

```
public static boolean isWay(int[] a){

return isWay(int[] a, int ind, int way)
}

private static boolean isWay(int[] a, int ind, int way){
   if(way==0)
   return true;
   if(way > a.length-1, || way < 0 )
   return false;
   if(ind > a.length-1 || ind < 0)
   return false;

   return isWay(a, ind+a[ind], way-a[ind]) || isWay(a, ind-a[ind],way+a[ind]);
}
```

Comment: what is `return isWay(int[] a, int ind, int way)`? I'm guessing you wanted to set default values for that... right?

Comment: Did you try writing (unit) test cases?

Comment: @Lino more specifically, what is `ind` and `way`?  Also, does not compile, but if the errors are fixed (`return isWay(int[] a, int ind, int way)` -> `return isWay(a, 0, a.length - 1);` and `way > a.length-1, || way < 0` -> `way > a.length-1 || way < 0`), it works with your example input

Comment: a[a.length-1] is 5, its the last element....you need to describe better the problem you are trying to solve. You want to see if you can reach the last element starting from the first and summing/subtracting the in between elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code. It searches a way from the beginning (index 0) to the end (index a.length-1).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isWay(new int[] {2,4,1,6,4,2,4,3,5}, 0));
    System.out.println(isWay(new int[] {2,7,3,8,5,1,2,1,2}, 0));
    System.out.println(isWay(new int[] {7,7,7,7}, 0));
}

public static boolean isWay(int[] a, int index) {
    if (index == a.length-1) return true;
    if (index > a.length-1 || index < 0) return false;
    return isWay(a, index+a[index]) || isWay(a, index-a[index]);
}
```

Comment: your answer is good but what about this array: int[] a = {1,4,3,1,2,4,3}, you'll get a stack overflow since the algorithm will add at a[1] +4 to a[5] and than a[5] - 4 = a[1] with no end.

Comment: You are right. I will have again have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isWay(int[] a)
{
    return isWay(a,0);
}
private static boolean isWay(int[] a, int ind)
{
    if  (ind < 0 || ind>a.length-1)
        return false;
    if  (a[ind]<0)
        return false;
    if  (ind == a.length-1)
        return true;
    int tmp = a[ind];
    a[ind] = -1;
    return  isWay(a, ind+tmp) || isWay(a, ind-tmp);
}
```